# Python/Mido crashing without any error message

Tags: python, midi

I'm pretty new to Python and MIDI processing, however what I see does not seem normal to me.

In this code, `listen_input` MIDI callback crashes without any error:

```py
import mido
import time

def listen_input(message):
    print('input:', message)
    print(1)
    filtered_on_message = copy.copy(message)
    filtered_on_message.velocity = 50
    output_message(filtered_on_message)
    print(2)

inport = mido.open_input('reface CP', callback=listen_input)
outport = mido.open_output('reface CP')

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

outputs:

```
input: note_on channel=0 note=79 velocity=81 time=0
1
input: note_on channel=0 note=79 velocity=0 time=0
1
input: note_on channel=0 note=79 velocity=77 time=0
1
input: note_on channel=0 note=79 velocity=0 time=0
1
```

`print(2)` is never called.

I'm guessing those errors are displayed in a separate process or something, or maybe a log, due to the callback?

Any idea?

Comment: The callback may be supressing exceptions. Add a try/except to the function, print 3, then re-raise. If that's the problem, you could then print the traceback for more details.

Comment: That's it! I'd accept your answer if you wrote it as such. However, are those exceptions logged somewhere?

Comment: What is output_message? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc that is a reproducible example, and missing output_message is precisely the reason of the crash – although the question was about the absence of error message about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in `listen_input` raised an exception. Taking a quick look at the source code for `mido`, callbacks (some callbacks at least) are called from a background thread. This code doesn't seem to do much error processing at all and includes the message

```
# TODO: exceptions do not propagate to the main thread, so if
# something goes wrong here there is no way to detect it, and
# there is no warning. (An unknown variable, for example, will
# just make the thread stop silently.)
```

and it appears that `mido` tries to terminate the callback thread. This can't have been successful because you see more than one print, but it's best to assume that all exceptions in callbacks are going to be a disaster.

You'll need to add your own try/except to each of your callbacks. In the following example I'm using Python `logging` to log messages as something I randomly called 'midi_if'. You can use any name you want.

Python logging is split into two basic roles. Things like `listen_input` get their logger and write logging messages. The main program configures how logging messages should appear. I went with the simplest `basicConfig` but there are many options.

I also just logged a critical message and then supressed the exception so that it doesn't make it back to `mido`. That may need significant refinement. For instance, maybe you do want to re-raise the error and let mido terminate. Or figure out your own way to terminate your program.

```
import mido
import time
import logging

def listen_input(message):
    try:
        print('input:', message)
        print(1)
        filtered_on_message = copy.copy(message)
        filtered_on_message.velocity = 50
        output_message(filtered_on_message)
        print(2)
    except Execption as e:
        # extreme: suppressing all exceptions as apparantly anything
        # returned to mido causes the callback thread to exit. That
        # action may be a good thing and in such case you'd re-raise
        # some or all errors.
        logging.getLogger('midi_if').critical("mido callback failed")
        # raise

logging.basicConfig() # or more complicated logging as you wish
inport = mido.open_input('reface CP', callback=listen_input)
outport = mido.open_output('reface CP')

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

it appears that `mido` doesn't log the exception in any way.

Comment: Thanks for that long answer! Just reraise the exception in the callback's `catch`` worked well